# How to set public bool value in C# code behind, read in .ascx User Control?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to slightly modify a user control that is being loaded by various .aspx pages.

If I set a bool value in the .aspx.cs page

```
public bool showTemplateBGOption;

public bool TemplateBGOption
{
    set { showTemplateBGOption = false; }
}
```

How can I read the bool value `showTemplateBGOption` in the .ascx control that is rendered on the same .aspx page?

Comment: Add a getter to your `TemplateBDOption` property? But why do you have a public field in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `Page` property to the right type, the page property needs a getter.

(somewhere in your ascx codebehind):

```
MyPageType page = this.Page as MyPageType;
if(page != null)
{
    bool templateBGOption = page.TemplateBGOption;
}
```

But in this way you are hard-wiring the page with the `UserControl`. Instead the page should specify the `TemplateBGOption` to the `UserControl`.

(somewhere in your page's codebehind):

```
this.UserControl1.TemplateBGOption = this.TemplateBGOption;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inplement an Interface to All Pages that will use this property and then use it in the user control and in this way you can decouple a user control from a specific page but you do it to a "contract"

```
interface ITemplateBOption
{
 bool TemplateBGOption{get;set;}
}

Public MyPage : Page,  ITemplateBOption
{
 public bool TemplateBGOption 
 {
  get{...}
  set{...}
 }
}
```

In your User Control use like this:

```
ITemplateBOption page = this.Page as ITemplateBOption;
if(page != null)
{
    bool templateBGOption = page.TemplateBGOption;
}else
{
//do something, thrown an exception for example.
}
```